# wdio chrome headless is not running headlessly

Tags: webdriver-io, google-chrome-headless

Headless chrome doesn't seem to be headless for me.  I'm using wdio and have this as my configuration:

```
  capabilities: [
    {
      // maxInstances can get overwritten per capability. So if you have an in-house Selenium
      // grid with only 5 firefox instances available you can make sure that not more than
      // 5 instances get started at a time.
      maxInstances: 5,
      //
      browserName: 'chrome',
      args: ['--headless', '--disable-gpu', '--window-size=1280,800'],
      binary: '/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome'
    }
  ]
```

I'm also outputting what the capabilities are prior to the browser starting:

```
{
  "maxInstances": 5,
  "browserName": "chrome",
  "args": [
    "--headless",
    "--disable-gpu",
    "--window-size=1280,800"
  ],
  "binary": "/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome"
}
```

My chrome browser is launching and I can see webdriver driving the test.  Everything I have many posts doing it in this manner and it's supposed to just work.  What am I missing?

---

UPDATE

I've modified capabilities to be read in from an environment variable.  If I use BROWSER=chrome, I see the proper capabilities go through and the browser starts in chrome.  If I use BROWSER=firefox, firefox opens up and I see the proper capabilities.  If I don't use anything I see the proper capabilities, chrome opens up, but it's not headless.

```
const CHROME = {
  browserName: 'chrome',
};

const FIREFOX = {
  browserName: 'firefox',
};

const CHROME_HEADLESS = {
  browserName: 'chrome',
  args: ['headless', 'disable-gpu']
};

function getCapabilities() {
  let browser;

  switch(process.env.BROWSER && process.env.BROWSER.toLowerCase()) {
    case 'chrome':
      browser = CHROME;
      break;
    case 'firefox':
      browser = FIREFOX;
      break;
    default:
      browser = CHROME_HEADLESS;
      break;
  }

  return [Object.assign({maxInstances: 5}, browser)];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://gist.github.com/disintegrator/ff6e9341860e9b121099c71bc9381bd6

**Have the capabilities inside your chrome options.**

It works fine for me.

```
capabilities: [

{

      browserName: 'chrome',

      chromeOptions: {

        args: ['headless', 'disable-gpu'],

      },

    },

  ],
```

Comment: I `console.log(JSON.stringify(capabilities,false,2))` at onPrepare, beforeSession, and before and the capabilities are exactly what I expect, including the args.

Comment: You use selenium server right? Why have you mentioned the binary?

Comment: I am using selenium server.  I took it out and am having the same results.  I kept it in because the examples I saw had it in.

Comment: Have you given args inside a capabilities array?

Comment: Have the args inside chrome options that should work.

Comment: post it and i'll upvote it and select as answer, I just realized this as well.  Thank you

Comment: based on idea in another answer, I had to use "goog:chromeOptions" as key instead of chromeOptions mentioned in this answer

Answer (score 4):

To go along with the accepted answer, in newer version of Selenium (3.8 and higher) you may have to specify `chromeOptions` as `"goog:chromeOptions"`